gnu make: rule which is valid for every given target in combination with .PHONY
I want to write a Makefile which is able to forward all given targets to a Makefile in a different directory. For simplicity the forwarding itself is removed from the example, because the problem starts earlier.
But I struggle with the very basic things:

.PHONY: x

%:
    @echo Default rule

__dummy__:
    @echo No targets rule



If I call make without parms: "No targets rule" is printed what is expected.
If I call make y : "No targets rule" is executed, expected!
But if I call make x: make: Nothing to be done for 'x'. is printed which makes me wonder!

x as file or directory should be allowed to be in the current directory.
How can I forward all calls to make to catch one of my rules? In other words: How write a rule that picks all phony targets as well.

Why not just use the .DEFAULT: special target?
.DEFAULT:
        @echo Default rule

__dummy__:
        @echo No targets rule


That has also a problem: If I add .PHONY: x, because x may be present in my folder, the .DEFAULT rule is not used. It simply returns make: Nothing to be done for 'x'.

For anything you mark phony you can add it as an explicit target: .DEFAULT x: ; @echo Default rule should work.

... which makes it not longer a default rule. If I am able to know before execution all targets, I did not need the forwarding in my environment. To make all rules explicit will reverse my implementation idea.

I don't understand what you mean by "a default rule".  You have to list the targets you are going to declare phony in your makefile, in order to declare them phony.  If you have to list them as phony you can just as easily list them as part of the default target rule, and .DEFAULT will take care of any you don't list.  No?  If you  just don't want to list them twice then put them into a variable and re-use the variable with both .PHONY and the .DEFAULT target.

If you know you want to do this with all subdirectories for example you could use SUBDIRS := $(patsubst %/.,%,$(wildcard */.)) and use that with both .PHONY and .DEFAULT and you wouldn't have to list by hand anywhere.  I guess until you specify what the exact issue is it's hard to suggest a solution.  If what you want is to do it exactly like you wrote above without changing anything, well, that's not possible.

My given example is maximum reduced. My idea was exactly the opposite: I would make any MAKECMDGOAL  PHONY programmatically.

OK, so add $(MAKECMDGOALS) to the .DEFAULT target.
